# typescript @types/yup validate return undefined?

Tags: typescript, types, yup

I have been using yup for my typescript project for a while.  It requires @types/yup for the type definitions. I was using `v0.26.4` of it, and it was all good. But today I update the dependency to `v0.29.3`. Something is wrong here:

```
//The object schema constructor from 
<T extends object>(fields?: ObjectSchemaDefinition<T>): ObjectSchema<T>;

//changed to 
<T extends object>(fields?: ObjectSchemaDefinition<T>): ObjectSchema<T | undefined>;

//then for my validation code:
const validated = await CreateNewsValidator.validate(req.body); // T | undefined
//when i use validated, the error Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type X comes
```

My question is when will the validate method return undefined? and what is the workaround, should i switch back to 0.26.4? Why did they make this change?